# Can Javascript create multiple functions based on other multiple functions by itself?

Tags: javascript

I have a large code with multiple eventlisteners on various objects from my HTML, they are all 'click' listeners. Now I realise I want another eventlistener on all these objects. Besides the click listeners I want mouseenter listeners. I was already writing it all out, but I figured there should be an easier way to do this. 
This might be a little vague, but this is basicly what I have now:

```
object1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(condition1){
        function1();
    }
});

object2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(condition2){
        function2();
    }
});

etcetera etcetera
```

I want to keep these function, and create new ones with 'mouseenter' listeners. These new functions will all do the samething this if the respected condition is met for each object. So I want this:

```
object1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(condition1){
        function1();
    }
});

object1.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    if(condition1){
        myAnimation();
    }
});

object2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(condition2){
        function2();
    }
});

object2.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    if(condition2){
        myAnimation();
    }
});

etcetera etcetera
```

Like I said, I could write all the code, but there are over a 100 functions. It would be awesome if there were a way for Javascript to generate it with a function.

EDIT:

What I am doing is building a storyline(in VR with Aframe). There are a lot of elements which you can click, but only if the story allows it, that explains the conditions in the listeners. What I want to do now (which I realised too late), is an animation with the cursor whenever the cursor is hovering over the element which is the right one to click, so the user knows what to click without having to click all the elements in the room. So all the 'mouseenter' listeners will need the same particular condition as the 'click' listener to the same element. It still sounds vague, but I don't know how to explain this further.

Comment: `arrayOfObjects.forEach(o => o.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () ... ))` – Whenever you're doing the same thing with multiple things, you probably want some form of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your 'html objects' if you have a way of selecting them (css selectors). The following example assumes that each object you want to apply listeners to has a class of 'object'

```
var objects = document.querySelectorAll('.object');
[].forEach.call(objects, function(object) {
  // do whatever
  object.addEventListener("click", ...
  object.addEventListener("mouseenter", ...
});
```

And you can change what happens in the click function depending on the properties of 'object' if that's what you want.

If you don't / can't use a selector, you may have other ways of compiling an array of objects that you can iterate over and apply event listeners to them conditionally.

Comment: All the different objects need a specific condition, the same condition the matching 'click' eventhandler has. In your solution that wouldn't be possible I guess. I edited my question, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It's not clear at all @RobbertOl . I'm absolutely certain I can help you answer your question, but you're not giving enough detail. Javascript can absolutely easily dynamically generate multiple eventListener functions based on whatever conditions you want, for whatever amount of Nodes you want. But you have to be able to *specify what you want*.